# HTML selection option display on going 12 months

Tags: javascript, html

I want bind the current month and year with next 12 months to dropdown. I use the following code to bind the month and year.

```
function writeMonthOptions() {
            var myselect = document.getElementById("drp6"), year = new Date().getFullYear();
            var today = new Date();
            var optionValues;

            var gen = function (max) {
                do {
                    optionValues = months[today.getMonth() + max] + ' ' + year;
                    myselect.add(new Option(optionValues, optionValues), null);
                    max++;
                } while (max < 12);
            }(0);
        }
```

My html code:

```
    <select name="drp6" id="drp6"></select>
```

But I get the select option as below:
Jul 2015
Aug 2015
Sep 2015
Oct 2015
Nov 2015
Dec 2015
undefined 2015
undefined 2015
undefined 2015
undefined 2015
undefined 2015

How do I solve it? Thanks

Comment: `today.getMonth() + max` should use `%` operator => `(today.getMonth() + max) % months.length` otherwise you try to get something out of that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's only 12 months, if you try to get months[13] in `optionValues = months[today.getMonth() + max] + ' ' + year;` it'll be `undfined then.

Also, year should be a considerable part, that when you enter a new year, years value should be 2016.

You can change to:

```js
      

     //demo value.
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];


   function writeMonthOptions() {
        var myselect = document.getElementById("drp6"), year = new Date().getFullYear();
        var today = new Date();
        var optionValues;
    
        var gen = function (max) {
            var curMonth = today.getMonth();
            var curYear = year;  // presevere outer year value if you hava other use
            do {
                optionValues = months[curMonth] + ' ' + curYear;
                myselect.add(new Option(optionValues, optionValues), null);
    
                ++curMonth;
    
                // When months reach the 13th ele of months, advance to next year.
                if (curMonth === months.length) {
                    ++curYear;
                    curMonth = 0;
                }
    
                max++;
            } while (max < 12);
        }(0);
    }
    
    // test.
    writeMonthOptions();
```

```html
<select id="drp6"></select>
```

Comment: Well, did you check Elfayer's answer's output? I think it might not be correct as output as `Jun 2015`'s next month is `Jan 2016`.

Comment: @Elfayer Yeah, saw that, but the description part should also change as other step into this topic, the first sight should be your description, not script.

Comment: @fuyushimoya . Marked as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the `months` index to : `(today.getMonth() + max) % today.getMonth()`.

**EDIT change year :**

Also you need to adapt the year, this gives us : `optionValues = months[index % months.length] + ' ' + (year + Math.floor(index / months.length));`

That's all you need to change.

```js
window.onload = function() {
function writeMonthOptions() {
            var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            var myselect = document.getElementById("drp6"), year = new Date().getFullYear();
            var today = new Date();
            var optionValues;
            var index;
    
            var gen = function (max) {
                do {
                    index = today.getMonth() + max;
                    optionValues = months[index % months.length] + ' ' + (year + Math.floor(index / months.length));
                    myselect.add(new Option(optionValues, optionValues), null);
                    max++;
                } while (max < 12);
            }(0);
        }
    writeMonthOptions();
};
```

```html
<select name="drp6" id="drp6"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I want start from current month